# What is the meaning of the number after the comma in the product page? (e.g. BC547C,215)

Tags: production, naming-conventions

Relevant links from Mouser and Digi-key:

- https://mouser.com/ProductDetail/Nexperia/BC847C235?qs=me8TqzrmIYWk6FelXF%2FgZA%3D%3D
- https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/nexperia-usa-inc/BC847CW-135/1727-1880-2-ND/1232291

This is causing some confusion in our purchasing team. I could not find anything in the datasheets, so it seems to have no technical relevance.

Comment: https://www.nexperia.com/products/automotive-qualified-products-aec-q100-q101/automotive-bipolar-transistors/general-purpose-bipolar-transistors/transistors-single-npn/BC847CW.html lists it as the "orderable part number"

Comment: From the Nexperia site it looks like a packaging option rather than anything to do with the device. You may want to check with the assembly people to see what they can handle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is related to packing.

The [BC847C](https://www.nexperia.com/products/automotive-qualified-products-aec-q100-q101/automotive-bipolar-transistors/general-purpose-bipolar-transistors/transistors-single-npn/BC847C.html) has these two "orderable part numbers":

[image: references for BC847C]

As you can see, they are the same component in the same package (SOT23), but they differ by packing:

- `BC847C,215` is delivered as [Reel 7" Q3/T4](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/packing-information/SOT23_215.pdf) (3 000 pieces)
- `BC847C,235` is delivered as [Reel 11" Q3/T4, LargePack](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/packing-information/SOT23_235.pdf) (10 000 pieces)

Another example, for the NXP CLRC 633, the datasheet lists these references (and more):

[image: some of the references of the CLRC 633]

As you can see, the first two are both `CLRC66301HN`, both HVQFN32, but one is delivered on **one tray, with an MOQ of 490 pieces**, while the other is delivered as **5 trays, and the MOQ is 5 x 490 pieces**.

The same applies for the next 3 which are all `CLRC66302HN`, all HVQFN32, but delivered as **either 5 trays (MOQ 5 x 490), 1 tray (MOQ 490) or 1 reel (MOQ 6000)**.

Some retailers/distributors will sell the components in smaller quantities (they buy the larger reels/trays from the manufacturer and then pick the right quantities from each order or cut parts of the tape), while others will sell only the full trays/reels.

Depending on how many you need and any requirements for production it may or may not matter.

In the case of your Mouser link for instance, they order the `235` version, but allow you to buy either the full reel (10K pieces) or cut parts of the tape from 1 single component. They also have the `215` version, available as full reel (3K pieces) or cut tapes from 1 single component. If you need smaller quantities, it shouldn't matter which one you order, in this case the tape is exactly identical except for its length. You may end up with two different prices for exactly the same component based on whatever rule they have to compute the per-unit price from the full reel price/quantity. Here the difference is very small.

On a final note, the two links you provided point to two actually different references ([BC547C](https://www.nexperia.com/products/automotive-qualified-products-aec-q100-q101/automotive-bipolar-transistors/general-purpose-bipolar-transistors/transistors-single-npn/BC847C.html) and [BC547C**W**](https://www.nexperia.com/products/automotive-qualified-products-aec-q100-q101/automotive-bipolar-transistors/general-purpose-bipolar-transistors/transistors-single-npn/BC847CW.html)) which are actually different components, with different packaging (SOT23 v. SOT323) and different characteristics (different \$P_{tot}\$). So the number after the comma (probably) doesn't matter, but the reference before it does!

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same package.  One is SOT23 and the other SOT323.

The numbers are probably in the datasheet, but this is a basic engineering talking to marketing dealing with production issue.  Marketing should be talking to both.

From Mouser link:
[image]

If you google BC847C,235, you get:

[BC847C](https://www.nexperia.com/products/bipolar-transistors/general-purpose-and-low-vcesat-bipolar-transistors/single-bipolar-transistors/single-bipolar-transistors-100-v/BC847C.html)

[image]

Either BC847C,235 (Orderable part number - for us humans to remember) or 9335 896 00235 (12 digit code computers prefer) will get you that part.

All versions of the BC847C would have 9335 896 00 as a part number.  Last 3, the 235 correspond to Packing.

From Digikey link:
[image]

Google BC847CW,135, you get:

[BC847CW](https://www.nexperia.com/products/automotive-qualified-products-aec-q100-q101/automotive-bipolar-transistors/general-purpose-bipolar-transistors/transistors-single-npn/BC847CW.html)
[image]

And BC847CW,135 or 9340 217 80135 will get that part.

Comment: This is not related to the comma though, it is related to the C x CW distinction, and is explicitly mentioned in the datasheet